# Create custom context action on a page, Umbraco v12.3.3

Tags: umbraco, umbraco12

I'm looking for a way to add a custom action to the context menu when you right-click on an Umbraco page in the dashboard.
I'm using the latest version of Umbraco, v12.3.3.

I've found information about customizing the home page, but nothing in the context menu.

The idea would be to add an extra element under Notifications :
[image: When you right-click on a page, this is the contextual menu I'm talking about]

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/extending/section-trees/trees ? It describes how to implement a custom tree, but you can also use it to append existing trees, as far as I know. Look for `GetMenuForNode` for a code example of creating "right click" menu items - it *should* be possible to configure a custom TreeController so that it can add an extra menu item to content nodes.